# A software to play videos very fast?

Tags: video, media-player

I have security camera recordings whose video files are 1 - 8 hours in duration and I need to be able to view them in a short period of time to review long periods of time.

Windows Media Player supports 8 seconds per second but this really doesn't do the job for me. I'd have to sit and wait a very long time to get through 8 hours of footage.

If anyone knows a software that can do this please let me know

Comment: You should delete this question and ask this over on http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: VLC easily does 32x speed... you do need proper equipment, i.e. fast disks / CPU / etc to process the data at those speeds and not miss too much. Whatever software you use, if your system can't keep up, you'll have lag and you can miss a lot of events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agree witk Jakke.

VLC on the playback menu lets you alter the playback speed. I tried a full hd movie and up to 5x it did well, beyond that i don't know it choked (compression artifacts, maybe it my machine that sucks). But with a surveillance video it should be better, as they usually require data to process (lower res, b/w).

It also features on the View/Advanced controls it shows som useful tools like snapshots and frame by frame advance.